# Find and set IP version within nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, ipv6

From what I can tell [from this list](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), there is no dedicated nginx variable to check if the client is connecting via IPv4 or IPv6, since this server supports both. I'd like to set a variable to pass to PHP within `fastcgi.conf` like so:

```
fastcgi_param      IP_VERSION      $ip_version
```

Is there a way to determine the IP version without using [Evil Ifs](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and pass this along? I'm well aware you can perform this check within PHP, however we'd like to use nginx if possible, while still maintaining its stellar performance.

Comment: Maybe using `lua` script? Although that might be overkill for this.

Comment: @Marki555 You're probably right, that would be overkill! Thanks for the suggestion.